# Displaying Graph as Color Rendering in Android using MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library and it's doing my work perfectly. Just wanted to see what other will say about this Addon including the author.

I am getting a data from a spectrometer. The data is in the visual range. from 400nm to 700nm. Ranges from light blue, to yellow, to pink, to green, to red. Right now, For pink color it is showing only Pink color as a function of RGB, can i display this as a mixture of red and blue. There is one library for QT, discussed [here](http://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/specrend/) . I want to do the same.

Right now with MPAndroidChar library, I am getting this output
[image]

But i want to do something like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a feature like that is **currently not supported**.

You will have to **modify the library** to your specific needs to achieve this.

Comment: Hi @Philip Jahoda, do you think the latest libraries can do stuff like this? I have no integer array of colors and can i put area under curve with that color set?